# fulton and harris representation theory exercise 2.5 solution

Tags: representation-theory

Trying to solve Exercise 2.5:

If $V$ is a permutation representation associated to the group $G$ on a finite set $X$, show that $\chi_\nu(g)$ is the number of elements fixed by $g$.

Looking for hint to get started. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you mean $\chi_V(g)$?

Comment: Hint: The matrix corresponding to some $g\in G$ will be a permutation matrix, i.e. it will have precisely one $1$ in each row and column. Think of what the diagonal means in terms of this and what this says about the trace.

Comment: Thanks jonki. Yes it was supposed to be $\chi_V(g)$. My bad.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thanks. Wrote the following code snippet in SAGE to count number of fixed elements in Symmetric Group(3)-map(lambda x:(x,sum(x.matrix().diagonal())),SymmetricGroup(3)). yields [((), 3), ((1,2), 1), ((1,2,3), 0), ((1,3,2), 0), ((2,3), 1), ((1,3), 1)]